# Compare two files content using hashkey in java

Tags: java, file, hashcode, java-io

I am writing a code for for TCP client-server in which client will ask server for all files info that it has in some specified folder then client will compare that data with its local directory info and will perform download or delete operation accordingly. In other word client will sync its local directory with server directory. 
For comparing files i am generating hashkey of all files on server using code below but problem is that it is working fine for different name of files. But if i update content of a file this code returns same hashValue.

```
InputStream fis = null;
fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
MessageDigest md =  md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

int numRead = 0;
do {
    numRead = fis.read(buffer);
    if (numRead > 0) {
        total_size+=numRead;
        md.update(buffer, 0, numRead);
    }
} while (numRead != -1);

fis.close();
byte[] hashValue = md.digest();
```

So, if there is any solution that it will generate different key for different content of same file or is there any other way to compare files on both ends?

Comment: Hard to believe. Evidence?

Comment: Although generating the same hash for different content is certainly possible, you probably just have an error in your code.

Comment: File Name="abc.txt" content = "Testing1"  hashValue="[B@6d06d69c"

Comment: File Name="abc.txt" content = "Calculating6"  hashValue="[B@6d06d69c"

Comment: That's not the hash code. Are you just calling `System.out.println(hashValue)`? That's not a correct way to print an array. Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hashValue))`

Comment: Yeah you are right after using System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hashValue)) it gives different value. Thanks!!!